# Resizing iPhone keywindow's main view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Edit 2: When I start the app without the status bar on top everything behaves as planned. With the status bar I couldn't get the views to act as I wanted. It looks as if the UINavigationController keeps resizing the content view by subtracting the 20 pixels of the status bar. I don't know.

I created a simple UINavigationController-based application. The root view in this navigation controller is a UITableView. At a certain time I want to slide in a 80 pixel high view from the bottom. The whole view on the top (the one that is controlled by the UINavigationController) should resize and get 80 pixel smaller to make room for the new bottom view.

This is basically the code I use to repositioning the views:

```
-(void)showTeaser {
float adHeight = 80;

[adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.height, 320.0, 80.0)];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:adView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[adView setAlpha:1.0];
[adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.height-adHeight, 320.0, 80.0)];
[self.navigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 320.0, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.height-adHeight)]; 

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, self.view.bounds.size.height-adHeight)]; 

[UIView commitAnimations]; }
```

I lowered the Navigationbar's alpha, set the UITableviewController's view to red. The new view is purple.

This is what happens. First screenshot initial state. Everything is looking normal. Second screenshot shows state after changing the frames. The view of the UITableviewController is always pushed 20 pixel under the Navigationbar. Also, if I try to add more views to the keywindow, they always end up 20 pixel higher than I expect. It almost looks like the keywindow (minus the navigation bar) is pushed up 20 pixel.

Edit 1: No matter to what size I resize the view, it's always 20 pixel.

Do I make a mistake by adding views to the keywindow at all? Shouldn't I do this?

[alt text http://www.hans-schneider.de/iphone-seo/1.png](http://www.hans-schneider.de/iphone-seo/1.png) [alt text http://www.hans-schneider.de/iphone-seo/2.png](http://www.hans-schneider.de/iphone-seo/2.png)

Comment: I already played with the autoresizing masks of my tableviewcontrollers view but this didn't change the basic problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I made the view of the `UINavigationController` a subview of a `UIView`, and manually set the bounds of the view for the `UINavigationController'.

```
//outerView is a UIView defined in the interface
outerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);]; 

//mainNavigationController is a UINavigationController defined in the interface
//rootViewController is a UIViewController (or inherited class) defined in the interface and instanced before this code
mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

//set the frame for the view of the navigation controller - 20 is due to the status bar
mainNavigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0.0, 20.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20);
```

Then later, when I go to resize, I resize the parent 'UIView' rather than the 'UINavigationController' view.

```
//change the outer view's frame to resize everything
//adHeight is a float defined earlier
outerView.frame = CGRectMake( 0.0, 20.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20 - adHeight);
```

This works well in an animation sequence.

**Edit 2011-05-12:** I updated the `outerView` frame to fill the screen.  This must be set to allow for touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the transform property of your tableview instead of manually changing it's frame? It may work out better, since the frame depends on the origin, and you only want to change it's size.